# Can anyone identify this insect from India?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Found this bug in Chennai. Curious to know what kind it is. Does it pose any danger?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely a bug - as indicated by the characteristic body form and the segmented (it should be five) antenna. My guess here is that this is *Nezara viridula*, also known as the "southern green stink bug" or the "southern green shield bug".

See this image (from [here](https://entnemdept.ifas.ufl.edu/creatures/veg/bean/southern_green_stink_bug.htm)):

[image]

Besides being a pest for agriculture, they are harmless and not toxic, although they can spread a stinking substance when threatened, hence their name. You can find more about them [here](https://entnemdept.ifas.ufl.edu/creatures/veg/bean/southern_green_stink_bug.htm) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nezara_viridula).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a common green stink bug - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_stink_bug

Give it a test. If you put it into a handkerchief and scare it a little, it should give off a foul smelling odor

Comment: Unfortunately the article linked by you limits the distribution of the bug to the US and parts of Australia.

Comment: The edges around its body also differ from the OP's images

Comment: the exact same bug is present in central Europe. I saw it today. So maybe the wikipedia article needs updating

Comment: the edges around it's body might be different because of the age difference. The body shape (hexagonal back) looks identical though